# SQL update table2 if table1 has value X?

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE group_id='8')
UPDATE table2 SET (...) 
WHERE usertype='numbereight'
```

what am i doing wrong? I need to update the usertype based on the group_id

Answer (score 1):

Try this instead:

```
UPDATE table2 
SET someColumn = 'somevalue'
WHERE EXISTS(SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE group_id='8')
AND usertype='numbereight'
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try with something like this :

```
UPDATE table2
SET (...) 
WHERE usertype='number eight' AND EXIST(SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE group_id='8');
```

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
UPDATE table2 
SET (...) 
WHERE usertype = 'numbereight'
AND exists (select * from table1 where group_id = '8')
```

Answer (score 1):

You can join the tables and update whatever fields you need

```
UPDATE t1 JOIN t2 ON t1.id = t2.id
SET
  t2.field = 'whatever'
WHERE
  t1.group_id= '8' AND
  t2.usertype = 'numbereight'
```

Comment: This is assuming that there is an ID in common to join on.  If you look at the original question/SQL, there is no related ID/data so this would not work.

Comment: @StevenMastandrea You're correct. I assumed the tables were related somehow